# Socket-programming in Android

Tags: android, sockets

i've written a short TCP-Server and TCP-Client in Java. Everthing worked fine while running the TCP-communication. Today I tried to implement my Server in an android-app and got problems with the serversocket.accept-method. Everytime the line with the method call serversocket.accept() is executed the systems breaks down.

Do I've to use threads to solve the problem. Or is there any other solution for this Problem?

Comment: Always put sockets in thread as they will block the UI thread when it is reading.

Answer (score 1):

The system doesn't "breaks". When you launch the "accept()" method, the program waits for an incoming connection. So if it's the activity thread that start this method, it freezes until it has an incoming connection.
But if an activity doesn't respond for over 5 second, the program is broken.

Try using a Thread, it's not hard really...